# Double ORDER BY sort with UNION statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
(
SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT d
FROM myTable
WHERE id =  "4h"
AND d <  "2011-12-08 12:00:00"
ORDER BY d DESC 
LIMIT 10
)tmp
ORDER BY d ASC
)
UNION (

SELECT d
FROM myTable
WHERE id =  "4h"
AND d >=  "2011-12-08 12:00:00"
ORDER BY d ASC 
LIMIT 10
)
```

I'm trying to get the 10 results before and after a particular ID by using two `SELECT` statements and a `UNION`. The first `SELECT` uses `ORDER BY DESC` to get the 10 preceding and then I attempt to envelope that in a second `ORDER BY ASC` to get all the results in `ASC` order but for some reason it does not work.

Here is what I get currently for a result:

```
d
2011-12-08 08:00:00
2011-12-08 04:00:00
2011-12-08 00:00:00
2011-12-07 20:00:00
2011-12-07 16:00:00
2011-12-07 12:00:00
2011-12-07 08:00:00
2011-12-07 04:00:00
2011-12-07 00:00:00
2011-12-06 20:00:00 <- These top 10 results should ASC!
2011-12-08 12:00:00
2011-12-08 16:00:00
2011-12-08 20:00:00
2011-12-09 00:00:00
2011-12-09 04:00:00
2011-12-09 08:00:00
2011-12-09 12:00:00
2011-12-09 16:00:00
2011-12-09 20:00:00
2011-12-11 20:00:00
```

And here is what I want:

```
d
2011-12-06 20:00:00
2011-12-07 00:00:00
2011-12-07 04:00:00
2011-12-07 08:00:00
2011-12-07 12:00:00
2011-12-07 16:00:00
2011-12-07 20:00:00
2011-12-08 00:00:00
2011-12-08 04:00:00
2011-12-08 08:00:00
2011-12-08 12:00:00
2011-12-08 16:00:00
2011-12-08 20:00:00
2011-12-09 00:00:00
2011-12-09 04:00:00
2011-12-09 08:00:00
2011-12-09 12:00:00
2011-12-09 16:00:00
2011-12-09 20:00:00
2011-12-11 20:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(
  SELECT   d
  FROM     myTable
  WHERE    id = '4h' AND d <  '2011-12-08 12:00:00'
  ORDER BY d DESC
  LIMIT    10
) UNION ALL (  
  SELECT   d
  FROM     myTable
  WHERE    id = '4h' AND d >= '2011-12-08 12:00:00'
  ORDER BY d ASC
  LIMIT    10
)
ORDER BY d ASC
```